# Does my ISP sees that I am using someone else's PPPoE username/password?

Tags: network, network-scanners, internet, isp, network-access-control

I want to ask that does my ISP will be able to see that I am using username/password of someone else on my dialup PPPoE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you login at your ISP on PPPoE with username/password the ISP will of course see who is logging in. It might also see which line the requests comes in. If the use of the credentials is restricted to specific lines it might detect misuse or it will simply not allow login. Even if use is not restricted to specific lines it can detect if these credentials are used on multiple lines at the same time.